# AngularJS - How to add an app in a particular state to a HTML element

Tags: angularjs

So lets say my app is called myApp, and the controller I wanna use is MyCtrl. So I can include this app in a div tag like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```

Lets say there are a few states, and usually I would use the router to map the states to the URL like this: http://example.com/state1 or  http://example.com/state2.

If I wanna include this app in state2 into the div tag, is there a way to do this? I'm kinda new to angular, basically I wanna be able to build a page that includes pieces of different modules into different parts of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ng-include: Fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment.

From Angular docs: [AngularJS API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
   <option value="">(blank)</option>
  </select>
  url of the template: <code>{{template.url}}</code>
  <hr/>
  <div class="slide-animate-container">
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I mean, to pull in all the parts of what would be associated with a state, but without using URLs. Pulling in multiple templates and controllers into a single page. So now I can specify the app, the controller and the template. Is there a way to pass in parameters? For example, the controller loads different questions depending on what the ID is.

Comment: In this case, you should use angular directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.   by using directives you can define your templateUrl, and send parameters with isolated scope.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to user [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for that. Specifically, you will use the [ui-view](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view) directive to specify where a state's template goes into it's parent template, or the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ui-view>
     //here goes your states
  </div>
</div>
```

// inject $stateProvider in your module and config function like:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider.state("home.state1",{
   url:"home/state1"
   templateUrl:templatename.html,
   controller:MyCtrl,
}).state("home.state2",{
   url:"home/state2"
   templateUrl:templatename.html,
   controller:MyCtrl,
});
```

})

Comment: go through this link for more details.